# How do I filter news articles out of my Google search?

Tags: google-search

I'm trying to google a topic which has a lot of heavy media coverage. I'm looking for technical details though, not any media coverage. The problem is the most combinations of search queries end up with pages of news articles and not the technical details I’m interested in.

Is there a way to get Google to filter out results from all news sources?

Comment: I found this result because I'm fed up of trying to find technical data and statistics related to COVID-19 only to be bombarded with news sites in every set of search results.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude keywords using `-`, so you could try adding `-news` (or other keywords that you don't want) to your query.
You can also use `-site:example.com` if you want to exclude a particular website.

If that doesn't work, you could try going to the wikipedia article and looking at the sources

Finally, if your topic is described in scientific literature you could search on scholar.google.com